# tslib : cross-compiling test scripts

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to embed tslib on an ARM system ; I cross-compiled the library, and it seemed to be okay unless for the test scripts. Indeed, they don't work at all on my arm platform because they tryed to link libraries with the path from the compiling platform.

Here is my example : I compiled from /home/jdl/tslib ; the bug on the arm system :

```
/home/ts_calibrate: cd: line 1: can't cd to /home/jdl/tslib-1.0/tests
/home/ts_calibrate: eval: line 1: /usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-gcc: not found
```

Second line is my toolchain ; don't understand why the script is looking for the toolchain as it is supposed to be compiled ?

I saw that there is some relative link during compilation :

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link /usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-gcc  -DGCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY --sysroot=/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools  --sysroot=/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools -o ts_harvest ts_harvest.o fbutils.o testutils.o font_8x8.o font_8x16.o ../src/libts.la -ldl 
libtool: link: /usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools/usr/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-gcc -DGCC_HASCLASSVISIBILITY --sysroot=/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools --sysroot=/usr/local/lib/star81xx-lsdk/tools -o .libs/ts_harvest ts_harvest.o fbutils.o testutils.o font_8x8.o font_8x16.o  ../src/.libs/libts.so -ldl
```

Do you have an idea for what goes wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the waste of time, I found my answer just after posting >< There is a *.libs* dir into the *tests* dir that contains the good versions of test softs. ;)